# Error page in IIS7 has text added to it

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

In my .net app, I redirect to an error page if an error occurs.

It works fine on my local IIS.

When I deploy to a web server, IIS7, it redirects to the error page, all fine, but these is text added to the error page

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. "

Could this be added via IIS7? It doesnt happen locally - also IIS7.

Comment: Try : Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager -> Default Web Site -> Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) to off in server's web.config file to find out what is the actual error. The "[500 Internal Server Error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)" could mean anything.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: I know what the error is, I just dont want that text displaying on the error page.

Answer (score 0):

> In my .net app, I redirect to an error page if an error occurs.

You might have already done this, but it may be worth checking the custom error page on both servers, perhaps one has the extra message hardcoded in there.